# Typeclass priority

Tags: scala, typeclass

I have a situation where I have a typeclass with a parameter that must be contravariant.  If I have an implicit object defined for both a baseclass and a subclass I get an "ambigious" error, where it doesn't know which implicit object to choose.  Is there a way to prioritize the implicit objects?  I've seen examples of priorities for implicit conversions, but never for typeclasses. Thanks

```
trait Coded[-X] { // contravariant
   val x: Int
}

def printCode[O1](p1: O1)(implicit ev: Coded[O1]) =
    println(ev.x)

class Baseclass
class Subclass extends Baseclass

object TEST {
  implicit object code1 extends Coded[Baseclass] { val x = 5 }
  implicit object code2 extends Coded[Subclass ] { val x = 6 }
}

import TEST._

printCode(new Subclass) // error: ambiguous
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean?

```
scala> trait Low { implicit object code1 extends Coded[Baseclass] { val x = 5 } }
defined trait Low

scala> object TEST extends Low { implicit object code2 extends Coded[Subclass ] { val x = 6 } }
defined object TEST

scala> import TEST._
import TEST._

scala> printCode(new Subclass)
6
```